# How can I get cascading reference dlls in one project to build into my main website project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I have two projects under one solution. One is an ASP.NET Web Application project, the other is a Class Library. The Web app project is my startup solution, and it has the class library project as a dependency.

In the class library project, I've added some new packages from our internal nuget server, as well as some required dependencies for these packages. For the sake of ease let's just say there's NugetPackage1, and NugetPackage2. NugetPackage1 depends on NugetPackage2, but I do not directly use NugetPackage2 anywhere in my class library project.

When I build the solution, I see NugetPackage1 and NugetPackage2 both in my bin folder for the class library. However, in my website project's bin folder I *only* see NugetPackage1.

I'm fairly certain it's automatically cleansing "unused" references, because when I directly use a class from NugetPackage2 in my class library and rebuild, it shows up in my website bin. What can I do about this?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? And are you using old style projects or the newer SDK style projects? I would expect SDK style project to work better in general, so it might be worth a try if you are using the older style of projects.

Comment: Are you still with us? How is your problem doing?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're relying on the build but you need to publish. One thing you can do is to add the following to your ASP.NET project

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <OutDir>webOutput</OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You probably already have the `PropertyGroup`, so you just need to add `OutDir`

Once you build it (for release, as shown above), you should find folder `_PublishedWebsites`, and your DLL should be either there or directly in `webOutput` folder. In case you you don't see it under former and only see it in latter, you can add post-build event to copy it into `_PublishedWebsites`

The bottom line, to have all necessary DLLs collected into bin, you need to Publish rather than Build.

Comment: There is a valid question there about SDK projects ^^. But since you're using VS2017, my answer is based on that. This is an old format project. With SDK projects it is even more essential to call `dotnet publish` rather than use MSBuild command when it comes to distribution